# Округление значений height (CSS, JQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Есть таблица и в ней определена высота строк (например, в данной строке 19,5px; строки разные):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Можно ли средствами сss (jQuery) округлить значения до целого числа?

Comment: если JS, то `Math.ceil()`, если CSS, то только фиксированная высота

Comment: нашел еще такой вариант через LESS, но мне не подходит:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17495302/can-numbers-be-rounded-math-term-using-less-css

Comment: это то же самое что просто указать `height: 20px;`

Comment: да, но дело в том, что высота строк разная: не везде 20px

Comment: css'ом округлить случайные значения невозможно. Так что только js.

Answer (score 1):

Ванильный JavaScript

```js
document.querySelectorAll("*").forEach(function(item, index) {
item.height = Math.ceil(parseInt(getComputedStyle(item).height));
});
alert(document.querySelector("div").height)
```

```html
<div style="height:50.6px; background:red;"></div>
```

Jquery

```js
$("*").each(function(){
this.height = Math.ceil(parseInt(getComputedStyle(this).height));
});
alert($("div").height());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="height:50.6px; background:red;"></div>
```

Comment: `Math.ceil(parseInt` - сомнительная комбинация. int уже сам целый. `parseFloat` тогда уж. Ну либо просто единицу добавить.

Answer (score 1):

- Для округления без jQuery используй `Math.round`.
- jQuery сам округляет значения до целых пикселей.
- Свойства `clientWidth`, `offsetHeight` и подобные возвращают округлённое значение.

[image: скриншот результата]

А вообще с округлением надо быть осторожнее, так как из-за половинки пикселя текст может перенестись на другую строку: https://stackoverflow.com/q/40517229/4928642.

```js
window.onload = function () {
  function process(p) {
    console.log(p.textContent)
    console.log("  getComputedStyle: " + getComputedStyle(p).width);
    console.log("  scrollWidth: " + p.scrollWidth);
    console.log("  jQuery: " + $(p).width());
  }

  process(document.querySelector("p"));
  process(document.querySelector("p + p"));
};
```

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Shrikhand', cursive;
}

p {
  outline: 1px dotted red;
  float: left;
  margin: 0 1em 0 0;
}

.as-console-wrapper.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 180px;
}
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Shrikhand" rel="stylesheet">
<p>How to get my size?</p>
<p>How to get the size?</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Конкретно в вашем случае используйте функцию `clientHeight` для получения целой высоты.

Для округления других значений используйте метод `toFixed([digits])`, который форматирует число, используя запись с фиксированной запятой. Примечательно, что данный метод можно использовать для стабилизации значений с запятыми от 0 и до 20 включительно.

```js
var num = 19.518903453;

alert(num.toFixed(0)); 
alert(num.toFixed(1)); 
alert(num.toFixed(2));
```